# Error running '__rvm_make -j12' while installing ruby 2.5.0 on CentOS

Tags: ruby, centos, rvm

I am setting up a new server and I have installed rvm version 1.29.9-next (master). I get the following error when I run rvm install ruby-2.5.0

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j12',
please read /home/projecty/.rvm/log/1564035272_ruby-2.5.0/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

make.log reads

```
compiling ./main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling miniinit.c
compiling dmyext.c
generating miniprelude.c
making dummy probes.h
compiling bignum.c
compiling class.c
compiling compar.c
compiling compile.c
compiling complex.c
./tool/generic_erb.rb:11:in `require': ./tool/colorize.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
...O.popen("tput smso", "r", err: IO::NULL, &:read) rescue nil)
                              ^
./tool/colorize.rb:7: dynamic constant assignment
...put smso", "r", err: IO::NULL, &:read) rescue nil)
                              ^
./tool/colorize.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tAMPER, expecting '='
...t smso", "r", err: IO::NULL, &:read) rescue nil)
                              ^
./tool/colorize.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected kRESCUE_MOD, expecting kTHEN or ':' or '\n' or ';'
... err: IO::NULL, &:read) rescue nil)
                              ^
./tool/colorize.rb:35: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end
        from ./tool/generic_erb.rb:11
make: *** [miniprelude.c] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why but rvm install ruby-2.5.0 ran successfully after I installed ruby 2.6.3 (latest stable).